error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'free'|
strutto *head,*cdm;

head=&a;
cdm=head;
a.next=&b;
b.next=&c;
c.next=NULL;

do{
    printf("%d\n",cdm->dato);
    cdm=cdm->next;
}   while(cdm!=NULL);

 free(a);
 free(b);
 free(c);

I'm getting this error while trying to free the lists  error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'free'|
The stdlib its already included

What is strutto? What are a, b, c?

If you can legally use a.next, then a cannot be a pointer and you cannot pass it to free. They must be plain variables of struct type. You can only pass an address to free that you received from malloc and corresponding functions.

@Gerhardh i tried with
 free(a.dato);
 free(b.dato);
free(c.dato);

and it seems to work ty

Without seeing your code, this information does not really useful. We don't see if you allocated memory for these variables or if they were NULL pointers (which you can also legally pass to free)? You code is way too incomplete to tell anything about it.

cdm->dato seems to be an int as you have printf("%d\n",cdm->dato). If that's the case, free(a.dato) is blatantly wrong. And if cdm->dato is not an int, then printf("%d\n",cdm->dato) is wrong.  Please read all the preceeding comments and [edit] your question accordingly, so we can stop the guesswork. Also read this: [ask], this will help you improve your question.

If you can use . operator to access struct members then your a, b, & c are objects (structs), not references (pointers) to structs.
free function requires the parameter to be a pointer and this pointer has to reference the object which was allocated by the malloc, calloc or realloc.
As a, b, & c are structs you can't use free.
